# Removing duplicate data from the query with different condition

Tags: ssrs-2008, duplicates

In the view I've created this query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ClientCode, ClientName, Address1, Address2, City, Country, CreatedBy, CreatedDate
FROM 
Contact
GROUP BY 
ClientCode, ClientName, Address1, Address2, City, Country, CreatedBy, CreatedDate
```

Which will give me this result,

```
001   ABC   Lot No,   Road,   City B,   US    Alice    03/04/2012
001   ABC   Lot No,   Road,   City B,   US    Benny    04/04/2012
```

How should I design my query so that I can filter out the duplicate data? I wanted to ignore the two fields - CreatedBy and CreatedDate by showing only 1 row of data. This is the result I wanna get.

```
001   ABC   Lot No,   Road,   City B,   US    Alice    03/04/2012    !OR!
001   ABC   Lot No,   Road,   City B,   US    Benny    04/04/2012
```

I want the query to have the ability to filter out duplicate data by comparing only the ClientCode, ClientName, Address1, Address2, City and Country. The reason of keeping the CreatedBy and CreatedDate is because I have to include it in another interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ranking function to get the most recent contact details for each address, based on the most recent date:

```
with recentContact as
(
  select *
    , mostRecentRank = row_number() over
    (
      partition by ClientCode
        ,ClientName 
        ,Address1 
        ,Address2 
        ,City 
        ,Country
      order by CreatedDate desc
    )
  from contacts
)
select ClientCode
        ,ClientName 
        ,Address1 
        ,Address2 
        ,City 
        ,Country
        ,CreatedBy
        ,CreatedDate
from recentContact
where mostRecentRank = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2edd/2).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I was having this issue about how should I select the data if it duplicates, now by choosing the most recent one it makes sense! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

try to add

`GROUP BY field`

Where field should be any field that is equal like clientname

In your special case, you can add multiple fields to GROUP BY like

`GROUP BY clientname, clientfoo ..`

Comment: I've tried to GROUP BY ClientCode, ClientName, Address1, Address2, City, Country, CreatedBy, CreatedDate. But it doesn't work.

Comment: And how would he select createdBy and createdDate with that ? He would have to select it using an aggregate function, right ?

Comment: What I want is the query that will not return me duplicate data (same piece of info for ClientCode, ClientName, Address1, Address2, City, and Country fields), by ignoring the CreatedBy and CreatedDate fields.